# Set Up Second Ethernet LAN with One Network Card

Tags: networking, 16.04, ethernet

I have a workstation running Ubuntu 16.04. The computer has a single NIC which is ethernet only.

My work environment is setting up a second network to act as the primary connection to the internet and our servers, and using another network as a fallback in case the first drops.

I can't seem to find out how to set up this other network on my system and in my Network Settings I don't have the option to add another wired network profile. I've already tried adding an entry in `/etc/hosts/interfaces` for `eth0:0` and this killed my network connection entirely.

How can I achieve this? I don't mind having to manually switch between the two profiles.

Comment: The word "network" is ambiguous. It may mean a set of cables connected to a set of switches (a _physical_ network). It may mean a VLAN (a _virtual LAN_, which works like a physical network except that a switch can serve more than one VLAN). It may mean a set of IP addresses (a subnet).  Since you say that this is for "fallback" I presume it's a physical network; in this case you just plug the other cable in the port and it should work.

Comment: Yes, it's a physical network with its own router and break-out point to the internet. I believe one network is on the 192.168.1 range and the other is on the 192.168.10 range. There's a part I missed out by accident. My machine is connected via a switch, and a network administrator is handling the network methodology and setup. Apparently others have been able to set up their machines to speak with both networks but for some reason I'm having difficulties.

Comment: Simply disconnect and reconnect should work. _Should_.

Comment: Ah, I've found the issue. There's some networking magic going on behind the scenes. I'm not sure this would go well into an answer as it seems to be specific to our use case. I spoke to our network admin and he's disabled DHCP on the router to allow both networks to run alongside each other, along with some other changes and now I'm able to connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My own use-case is quite complex, but a general answer to setting up multiple networks on a single NIC can be broken down into several steps. Bear in mind with this answer that my system is connecting to one network with DHCP and one without it.

I've tried to keep the answer generic to help others but bear in mind that other use cases may require different settings or approaches.

1. Open the `Network` application.
2. Click `Add Profile...`
3. Enter the details required. In this case, IPv4, requiring an IP address, netmask and gateway.
4. Fill in the DNS settings. I was able to use Google's DNS of `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`.
5. Fill in the Routes settings. I was able to leave mine blank and have `Automatic` set to `on`.
6. Click `Apply`.

There should now be two network profiles with the names you've assigned to them. To connect to either one, simply click it within the Network application. In my case, I am using two different gateway servers which can be seen in the screenshots below. When I connect to either of the two, my public IP address changes, which is as expected.

[Settings in the Network app for one profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3F3D.png)

[Settings in the Network app for the second profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEWhn.png)